# Replacing special characters in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm reading out data from some old Cobol binary data files through a JDBC connection in Java on Linux (Ubuntu). The Swedish characters å,ä,ö,Å,Ä and Ö comes out as small boxes with four characters in them. Here is an example.

[image]

When running the program they actually just comes out as `` empty boxes in the console. I get the boxes with the text in them when I copy paste the output to a text editor. I think these characters are coded with `ISO/IEC 8859-15` but I'm not sure. I like to replace the characters and thought I do `myOutptString.replace("", "Ä");` and then I'll do the same thing for the other characters. The problem is that I'm not able to put the empty boxes as `target` in the `replace` function. What should I put in the `target`? Maybe it is not even possible to use the `replace` function for this.

Comment: You need to read the file with the correct encoding.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around when replacing characters/strings? As in `myOutputString.replace("Ä", "a");`. Now `Ä` will be replaced with `a`, unless those boxes are not read as `Ä` anymore.

Comment: @SLaks. I tried setting the encoding but it seems like it is not `ISO-8859-15`. Is there anyway I can do the replacement?

Comment: @steven No I want to replace to the Swedish characters å,ä,ö,Å,Ä and Ö.

Comment: Maybe this can help you set the right encoding? [Wiki source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#On_computers)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the info as bytes and then try to construct your String using UTF-8 encoding. Your problem most likely is that your default encoding is different from that of your info. So in your code java tries to interpret the bytes according to your default encoding and fails. So if you just read bytes say into `byte[] buf` and then try to read it in this way:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf), "UTF-8"));
```

it might help. Ultimately you just need to figure out the encoding of your datasource

Comment: I'm not sure what the encoding is. Now though I managed to copy the "boxes" from the console into the editor and then it came out as codes, one example looks like this `\u0086` with this I'm able to replace it with regular characters.

Comment: Those are unicodes. So you can read them as UTF-8. Also, If you want a tool to convert Unicodes into Strings and vise-versa you can use my Open Source Library "Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison". See the paragraph "String Unicode converter". Here is the link to the article that explains in detail about the utilities in the library and how to use this library: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman